# How to require PHPTAL.php

Tags: php, phptal

How do I require `PHPTAL.php` that I added to my buildpath (PHP Include path folder)?

It would do with either an absolute or relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is in one of the folders in your `include_path`:

```
require('PHPTAL.php');
```

Otherwise simply specify the relative or absolute path to the file (if you use a relative one it must be relative to the path of the PHP script that was initially called by the HTTP request):

```
require('/path/to/PHPTAL.php');
```